# split application.css to overcome IE9 rule limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer-9, asset-pipeline

I am using css_splitter gem to split application.css to overcome 4095 rule limit in IE9.

app/assets/stylesheets/application_split2.css.split2

```
/*= include "application.css" */
```

config/environments/production.rb

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(application_split2.css)
```

app/views/layouts/application.html.haml

```
= split_stylesheet_link_tag 'application', :media => "all"
```

asset:precompile task succeeds and when i try to load the page, both application.css and application_split2.css files have the same content and the page is missing some of the styles. Am i missing something?

or Is there any other way of fixing the IE rule limit problem?

Comment: Why not manually create two application.css's? and just include half in one, and half in the other?

Comment: I did that. After splitting the css into two files, IE9 seems to have lost some rules and selectors(roughly 100). It may be the same case before splitting as well. Counted the rules and selectors using a js snippet in IE and firefox